# cURL php upload file detected as IPS attack

Tags: php, curl, firewall

Why my cURL upload file detected as IPS attack by forti firewall :

```
function post_files($url, $files,$data=array()) {


    if (!is_array($files)) {
        //Convert to array
        $files[] = $files;
    }
    $n = sizeof($files);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $data['file' + $i] = "@" . $files[$i];
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

Is there any curl option ?

Answer (score 2):

With this it seems like the request is from firefox:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6');
```

With this the upload seems to come from the actual site:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://domain you should have come from");
```